# How to redirect to a specific page in first login in laravel 5?

Tags: php, redirect, laravel-5

I am trying the latest laravel 5 recently by writing a simple web application. I am using the default login page provided by laravel 5. It works fine and I want to twist it a bit that the user will have a default password set by the system and the user will need to change the default password to their own at their first login.

I added a field called "first_login" in the default user table, with default set to "true". I have tested the password setting page by directly typing in the url and it works. Then, I changed the Middleware\Authenticate.php a bit, trying to redirect user to the changing password page at first login.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ($this->auth->guest())
        {
            if ($request->ajax())
            {
                return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
            }
            else
            {
                return redirect()->guest('auth/login');
            }
        }
        else if ($this->auth->user()->first_login == "true")
            return redirect('user/change-password/');

        return $next($request);
    }
```

However, this yields a redirect loop. What have I done wrong? And what should I do to redirect the user to the correct page?

Comment: can you show your routes file?

Answer (score 0):

Is the first_login field a string? By looking at your code it appears so. Try this

```
else if ($this->auth->user()->first_login == "true"){
    $this->auth->user()->update(['first_login' => "false"])
    return redirect('user/change-password/');
}
```

Comment: Not in front of a PC and don't have time to test the code yet, but even if this works, if the user didn't change the password (e.g. close the tab), the user will be able to get into the system without changing the password?

Comment: I have just checked the code on my PC, but this doesn't work.